# Retrieve idletimeout information from CLI command

Tags: jquery, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-elb

I am able to get information of the entire load balancer attributes, but I would like to filter/query only "IdleTimeout" under "ConnectionSettings".

The below command gives the entire information of the load balancer.

Please help me to filter it.

```
aws elb describe-load-balancer-attributes --region eu-west-1 --load-balancer-name my-elb-name
```

Output:

```js
{
"LoadBalancerAttributes": {
"ConnectionDraining": {
"Enabled": true,
"Timeout": 300
},
"CrossZoneLoadBalancing": {
"Enabled": false
},
"ConnectionSettings": {
"IdleTimeout": 60
},
"AccessLog": {
"S3BucketPrefix": "prefix",
"EmitInterval": 5,
"Enabled": true,
"S3BucketName": "saas.aws.st.my-elb.eu-west-1"
}
}
}
```

Comment: aws elb describe-load-balancer-attributes --region eu-west-1 --load-balancer-name Elb_Name --query "LoadBalancerAttributes[*].ConnectionSettings[*].[IdleTimeout]"

Answer (score 0):

You are querying just one LB, wildcards are needed.

```
aws elb describe-load-balancer-attributes --region eu-west-1 --load-balancer-name ELB_Name --query 'LoadBalancerAttributes.ConnectionSettings.IdleTimeout'
```

60

Comment: if i want to execute same for multiple ELB's does this works ?

`aws elb describe-load-balancer-attributes --region eu-west-1 --load-balancer-name "ELB_Name1","ELB_Name1"  --query 'LoadBalancerAttributes.ConnectionSettings.IdleTimeout'`

Comment: Also i'm trying to get the same information using Boto3

`import boto3
client = boto3.client('elb', region_name='eu-west-1')

response = client.describe_load_balancer_attributes(LoadBalancerName='ELB_Name')
for LoadBalancerAttribute in response['LoadBalancerAttributes']:
    for ConnectionSetting in LoadBalancerAttribute['ConnectionSettings']:
        Output = ConnectionSetting['IdleTimeout']
        print(Output)`